# Serialize records without id in embedded record mixin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data, mixins

I started looking on embedded record mixin for serialising/deserialising records with hasMany/belongs to relationship.

Model:

```
 App.Post= DS.Model.extend({

   comment: DS.belongsTo('comment'),
   name:     DS.attr('string')
 });

 App.Comment =DS.Model.extend({

  post: DS.belongsTo('Post'),
  value:   DS.attr('string')
 });
```

Serializer:

```
App.PostSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
   attrs: {
      comments: {embedded: 'always'}
   }
});
```

When i try to save the model,i got the following error.

```
   var model = this.store.createRecord('post');

    model.get('comments').pushObject(this.store.createRecord('comment'));


    model.setProperties({
        name: 'test'
    });

    model.save();
```

Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an id for App.Comment in an object passed to push . Only the error in browser console but to the backend ,data goes as expected.

So, i started looking for workaround and found something interesting in https://gist.github.com/vampolo/8f8237cce2b8a52ab9d4.

source : http://vincenzo-ampolo.net/2014/09/21/ember-data-embedded-records-without-ids-ready-to-go/

On following that link, i changed my serialiser as follows.

Serializer (changed):

```
  App.PostSerializer=DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,DS.NoKeyMixin, {
        attrs: {
          comments: {embedded: 'always',noKey: true}
        }
     });
```

But when i save the model now, i am getting the floowing error.

Uncaught TypeError: embeddedRecord.serialize is not a function.

I am stuck on this and looking for help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue! Thanks for sharing the problem.

Comment: Any chance you could add the key? It does not need to be called "id":

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
   primaryKey: 'ssn' // social security number
});